# Google Sheets Hide url

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I do have the following COLUMN `Q88` as per the following screenshot.

[image]

i want to Apply formula where if it's url so i want it to be displayed as `www.q88.com`

I know how to validate the url using `IFURL` but i don't know how to continue with it if it's url so i want to hyperlink with text label as am not familiar with google sheets at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Explanation:**

This is the Google Apps Script implementation of [marikamitsos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64832831/11225291) answer so please accept his answer if this one works for you.

- The only thing you need to do is to define the sheet name and the
  column letter. I used `"Sheet1"` and `H` respectively.
- The script will replace/overwrite every value in the chosen column with either
  itself or with the desire value if there is a match with the regular
  expression.

**Solution 1 - regular function:**

```
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; 
  const rng = sh.getRange('H1:H'+sh.getLastRow());
  const vals = rng.getValues().flat();
  const fvals=vals.map(v=>v.match("//(.*)/")?[`=HYPERLINK("${v}","${v.match("//(.*)/")[1]}")`]:[v])
  rng.clearContent();
  rng.setValues(fvals); 
}
```

**Solution 2 - onEdit trigger function:**

```
function onEdit(e){
  const row = e.range.getRow();
  const col = e.range.getColumn();
  const as = e.source.getActiveSheet();
  if(as.getName() == "Sheet1" && col == 8){
  const v = e.value;
  const fv = v.match("//(.*)/")?`=HYPERLINK("${v}","${v.match("//(.*)/")[1]}")`:v;
  e.range.setValue(fv);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but the script is doing a different thing than my desired. my target is to convert `https://www.example.com/id=123` to an hyperlink [https://www.example.com](https://www.example.com/id=123)

Comment: I will update my answer later but what you ask is very simple. You can pass the resulting string into a hyperilink formula and `setFormula` via the script. Anyway, if you want the solution now I would advice you to try it out it is really simple to create a formula using Google scripts. If you can wait for 5-7 hours I will update my answer. @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη

Comment: Thanks Marios, am not familiar with Google sheets at all but i will give it a look right away. thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I will update my answer in 5-7 hours regardless of what you will decide to do. Feel free to try it yourself or not :) I just can't update it right now.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out and if i did it so i will let you know :P

Comment: Great answer @Marios. Just what was needed. I wish I could accept it as well.

Comment: @Marios thank you. i don't want to tired you but it's not hyperlink the url. it's just switch `https://www.q88.com/id=123` to `www.q88.com` and once you click to it so it's just take you to q88.com itself

Comment: Here's a dummy data where i triggered the script so you can insert any data and see how it's will be displayed after. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1q7URzsol7q8a4uOX55CsS9D0PNpJDl_O94voXMnBPio/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη You didn't mention in your original question that you are running the script via an onEdit installable trigger. Please remove that trigger since you can simply use `onEdit`. Another note is that if you use onEdit trigger you can't use the first solution in my answer. Because every time you edit something you will replace the full column of H with the correct values but then if you edit again anything, it will remove the hyperlinks and replace the hard copy values instead. There are two options. Use the first solution **once** and never run it on the same data again.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη or use the second solution but **remove** the trigger you have manually set up. `onEdit` works as a trigger itself. You don't need to manually enable it.

Comment: @Marios thanks a lot for clarification and taken time explaining things for me. i really appreciated it. regarding the trigger I've just applied it to make it easy for you to see the output directly without needing to run the script. thanks again

Answer (score 2):

Please try

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(O1:O,"//(.*)/"),O1:O))
```

*(adjust ranges to your needs)*

[image]

Functions used:

- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`REGEXEXTRACT`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244)

Comment: i don't want to create new column, i just want to apply it within same field

Comment: How do you get the results in your column? I mean what formula do you use? Please share some original data and the formula.

Comment: no worries about the data. i just show it for you and then i will delete the sheet

Comment: I've deleted it

Comment: If you want `www.q88.com` in the same column you will need a script. If it is ok with you to have a different column please use my formula in a new column next to it.

Comment: Please check the new formula. It exactly replicates your existing column **and**, at the same time, replaces your URLs this just `www.q88.com`

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη I added a script implementation in case you want to replace the values in the same column. But please don't accept my answer. The answer is taken by marikamitsos but modified to work on a script.